# tensorflow installation problems

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried installing tensorflow on my ubuntu 14.04 64bit machine:

```
sudo pip2 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

for python 2.7

When I run `import tensorflow as tf` in the console I get error

> Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel, you should
>   not try to import tensorflow from its source directory; please exit
>   the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from
>   there.

Google didn't provide a good answer to this, any thoughts?

Comment: Did you start Python from the tensorflow source directory (e.g. a clone of the GitHub repository)? If so, Python can get confused by the two possible `tensorflow` packages in its search path. Try changing to another directory and restarting Python.

Comment: You know, you can use docker for using tensorflow. The instruction is on their site. Pycharm 5.0 offers nice integration with docker. So, then you can use tensorflow with pycharm.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what directory you're running your python client from? Alternatively, let us know if you have resolved this yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It makes it easy to install all dependencies needed (most are automatically installed) and there are multiple options for installing tensorflow.

```
conda install tensorflow
```

or

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot import tensorflow whilst you are in the tensorflow source directory. Change Directory i.e. `cd ..` first before running python.

I've emphasized the key part of your error: "Error importing tensorflow. Unless you are using bazel, **you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory**; please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there."

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote so I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with your tensorflow installation version and environmental configuration. I have also faced same issue, as I had installed tensorflow for Python version 3.5 while my system has 3.6.

Select the correct wheel for your installation. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The error message also contained the line "ImportError: No module named google.protobuf". As mentioned here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1415 , a workaround for this problem is to create an empty __init_.py file in the tensorflow/google directory, where you should also have the protobuf folder. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Before you type command `python` in terminal, your workspace shouldn't be the directory which contain the tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl.
i.e. your workspace should be different from the directory where tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly suggest you to use virtualenv. I have been suffering in installing tensorflow as well as its dependencies for weeks until I learn about virtualenv. You can follow the official tutorial to install it. (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html) And it comes with all the library that you are likely to use. Also, you can modify your environment in your Python IDE. Then you don't have to active and deactive virtualenv every time you use it.ery Very convenient
!

Answer (score 2):

You will see this issue if you start python when you are working inside the source tree of tensorflow. (wherever you cloned the git repository)
Python gets confused about what to import when you run "import tensorflow" (the one in your directory or the system installed one).
That is what the error message is trying to say.

Simply change to your home directory, or a new empty directory and it should work.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you please explain a bit what do you mean by "Simply change to your home directory, or a new empty directory"? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you are on a linux or macos terminal, `cd ~` or `cd <another folder>` where <another folder> does not contain tensorflow source code.

Comment: what is "source tree" of tensorflow? I followed getting started guide and  couldn't even get started :-(

Comment: Source tree is the actual source code of tensorflow. When you `git clone http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`, then `cd tensorflow`, it is the directory you will be in, and any directory under that.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org), it's really helpful for ML and data science job.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev

export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

And then run python. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

it's very painful if you're not very familiar with python but you install tensorflow from source code. you cannot import tensorflow from your tensorflow directory. If you exit your TENSORFLOW_ROOT, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to install microsoft visual c++ redistributable 2015 , 2017 , 2019 
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Answer (score -1):

I ran in to a similar issue and it turned out it was because the protobuf dependency wasn't met, or there was an issue with protobuf. I would uninstall protobuf:

```
>> sudo pip uninstall protobuf
```

Then re-install:

```
>> sudo pip install --upgrade protobuf
```

If that doesn't work, try uninstalling and re-installing both protobuf and tensorflow. If you are building from source, [check out this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1402)

Answer (score -1):

It shows this kind of error because the python s/w you installed is not supported by tensorflow.
So uninstall the previous version of python and go to the `tensorflow` installation doc then install the specified python software instructed there.