# How to solve ImportError even Rasa_nlu and tensorflow are installed successfully

Tags: tensorflow, rasa-nlu

I faced the following error after installing Rasa_nlu and Tensorflow.

```
ImportError: Failed to import `tensorflow`. Please install `tensorflow`. For example with `pip install tensorflow`.
```

Before getting the above error message, I have successfully import the following packages as shown below.

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data  import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa_nlu import config
import tensorflow as tf
```

The following is the version of Anaconda3, Tensorflow, Rasa_nlu and python.

Anaconda-client: 1.6.14, 
Anaconda-navigator: 1.8.7, 
Anaconda-project: 0.8.2, 
Python: 3.6, 
Tensorflow: 1.8.0,

Could someone help me about me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252888/tensorflow-installation-problems
OS please? Did you go with conda or pip?

Comment: It is windows 10 64 bit i7. For rasa_nlu, I used pip install rasa_nlu. For tensorflow, I used 4 scripts. conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5, activate tensorflow, conda config --add channels conda-forge, conda install tensorflow

Comment: Thank you very much manohar amrutkar. I have solved the problem.